# How to concatenate strings in python using for loop?

Tags: python

What is the difference in adding an `i` in `for` loop to an empty string using `i` and `str(i)`

```
s=''
for i in range(6):
    s=s+ 'i'
print (s)
```

expected output: 012345

I am getting the expected output when I  use the `s=s+ str(i)`. please explain the concept behind this

Comment: `'i'` is the literal string `i`. `str(i)` constructs a string with the value of `i`, which in this case is the numbers 0 through 5.

Comment: `'i'` is the character "i". `i` (without the quotes) holds the value of your `for` loop variable and goes from 0 to 5. Using `str(i)` casts this integer to a string.

Comment: *"to an empty string using i and str(i)"* You aren't using `i` you are using `'i'`.

Comment: If instead of `s = ''` you had `s = 'i'`, what would you expect to happen? Why would the string literal `'i'` mean and do different things inside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

`'i'` is a single character (i) string. Whereas `i` is a variable used to iterate over your range, so it will take every value inside that iterable: 0, 1, ..., 5

Btw, `''.join(map(str,range(6)))` is a preferred method by most.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can see that the error received is due to the variable `s` being a string and the variable `i` being an integer.

```py
>>> s: str = ""
>>> for i in range(6):
...   s += i
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Usually python can auto-convert (autobox) from one primitive data type to another, but in certain circumstances these conversions are not assumed for you. So by using `str(i)` you are forcibly converting the integer variable `i` to a string in order to concatenate to the rest of your string.  The following may make it clearer:

```py
>>> for i in range(6):
...   print(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
>>> for i in range(6):
...   print('i')
... 
i
i
i
i
i
i
>>> for i in range(6):
...   print(str(i))
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: *"Usually python can auto-convert (autobox) from one primitive data type to another"* This is only really true for numeric types: int, float, and bool (which is a subclass of int: `True` behaves like 1 and `False` behaves like 0). Also, "autobox" is a Java concept that doesn't really have an analogue in Python.

Answer (score 0):

- `'i'` is literally the string `'i'`.
- `str(i)` is the `str` type of the variable `i`, that is used to iterate over your `for` loop.

The code below will add multiple string `i` in the variable `s`. Since you added the string 'i'.
That's why you will get the result: `iiiiii`

```
s=''
for i in range(6):
    s=s+ 'i'
print (s)
```

However, the code below will add the string type of variable `i` in the variable `s`, since you used `str(i)`, which just changes the type of the variable.

That's why you will get the result: `012345`

```
s=''
for i in range(6):
    s=s+ 'i'
print (s)
```

`str(i)` will only change the variable's type to string, which will add the value of the variable `i`.
In contrast, `'i'` will only add the string `i`, literally.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should use `''.join(map(str,range(6)))`.

But I want to point out what is wrong in your code.

`range(6)` is the same as `range(0, 6, 1)`, it contains nothing but when iterated upon it produces numbers starting from 0 and ending at 6, with step being 1: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

`s = ''`, `s` is a `str` and you can't add `str` to `int`. You need to cast one to the other, casting `str` to `int` involves more work than casting `int` to `str`, so usually we just cast `int` to `str`.

You will get the following error if you try to do `'' + 1`:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Now to get `'012345'` using a for loop, you can use either of the following:

```
s = ''
for i in range(6):
    s += f'{i}'
print(s)
```

Or

```
s = ''
for i in range(6):
    s += str(i)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you surround a variable with quotes (eg. writing `'i'`), then that's no longer a variable, it is just a string (in this case, the character `i`) because that is how Python and most programming languages denote strings.

If you instead use `str(i)`, then the `str()` function takes the variable `i`, sees what is inside it (one of the integers between 0 to 5 in this case), and converts it to a string. Converting an integer to a string in each of the 6 iterations of the loop, tells Python that we don't want to treat our integers as numbers and do mathematical operations on them, like addition or subtraction. Instead, `str()` tells Python that we want to treat our integers as strings, and therefore do string operations on them, like concatenation(placing one character next to the other).